# Input Transformation with String Replace in B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a Claims Transformation as follows:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="FormatRedirectUri" TransformationMethod="StringReplace">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="redirectUri" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="oldValue" DataType="string" Value="/" />
    <InputParameter Id="newValue" DataType="string" Value="\" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="updatedRedirectUri" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Now in order to use this claims transformation as a input transformation in another technical profile I am using it like this:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="P1">
  <DisplayName>---</DisplayName>
  <Protocol
    Name="Proprietary"
    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
  />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">---</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
    <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="FormatRedirectUri"/>
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="redirectUri"  DefaultValue="{OIDC:RedirectUri}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
  </InputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I am using a claim resolver from the OpenIdConnect protocol which goes above the P1 tech profile in the user jouerney. But for some reason I getting an error from b2c saying that

> A Claim of ClaimType with id "redirectUri" was not found, which is required by the ClaimsTransformationImpl of Type "Microsoft.Cpim.Data.Transformations.StringReplaceTransformation" for TransformationMethod "StringReplace" referenced by the ClaimsTransformation with id "FormatRedirectUri" in policy

Any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

Both your claim transformation and your technical profile reference a claim named `redirectUri`, that error is saying that you've not defined a `ClaimType` with that name anywhere in your custom policies.

For example:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsSchema>

    <!-- Other claim types -->

    <ClaimType Id="redirectUri">
      <DisplayName>Redirect URI</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
    </ClaimType>

  </ClaimsSchema>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

You have to [define a claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema) before it can be used anywhere, even if it's only used internally within the custom policies to pass data around.

I'm also not sure that technical profile will work the way you want it to.

I think you want it to populate the `redirectUri` with the incoming request's `redirect_uri` and then replace `/` characters with `\` before passing that modified `redirectUri` to your API?

Due to the [order in which a technical profile executes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles), what I think will happen is that the transformation will replace the characters in `redirectUri` first, *then* set it to the incoming request's `redirect_uri`.

What you probably need to do is have a [claims transformation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile) that sets `redirectUri` as an `OutputClaim` and runs your claims transformation as an `OutputClaimsTransformation`:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="PopulateRedirectUri">
  <DisplayName>Normalise Redirect URI</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="redirectUri" DefaultValue="{OIDC:RedirectUri}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="FormatRedirectUri" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

You can then execute that as an orchestration step before your API call:

```xml
<UserJourneys>
  <UserJourney Id="YourJourneyNameHere">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
    
      <!-- Other journey steps -->

      <!-- these order numbers will be different in your policy -->
      <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange" >
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="Step-PopulateRedirectUri" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PopulateRedirectUri" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange" >
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="Step-P1" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="P1" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      
      <!-- Other journey steps -->
    </OrchestrationSteps>
  </UserJourney>
</UserJourney>
```

That should run things in the correct order.

Doing that, you'd also need to ensure your API technical profile is using the transformed claim type (`updatedRedirectUri`):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="P1">
  <DisplayName>---</DisplayName>
  <Protocol
    Name="Proprietary"
    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
  />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">---</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
    <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <!-- value will be taken from updatedRedirectUri but passed to the API as redirectUri -->
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="updatedRedirectUri" PartnerClaimType="redirectUri" />
  </InputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```